# Compiling .cpp file into Matlab MEX file

Tags: matlab, mex

I'm trying to compile a C++ function to use it with Matlab (2013a)? I'm using Mac OS 10.9. When I run the below command from the Matlab command line:

```
mex SEA.cpp
```

the following error appears:

```
SEA.cpp:6:10: fatal error: 'windows.h' file not found
#include <windows.h>
```

What am I missing?

Comment: You're missing the Windows OS

Comment: Then how can I compile the file on the Mac?

Comment: That's impossible to answer without seeing and understanding the contents of the file. You should contact the author.

Comment: How come then there is no problem when compiling the file on Windows but I have to know the content when compiling the file on the Mac?

Comment: The name of the missing file should be enough to answer that question. `Windows.h` contains types and function declarations specific to the Windows API. You'd run into the same problem if you `#include` a Mac OS X specific header and then try to compile the file on Windows.